# SSIS Event handling with Script task

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I have a script task for Event handler on OnPreexecute for Data Flow 
Task(executable).

Basically doing a data export to a flat file.

Script has

```
MessageBox.Show ("Everthing good")
```

SSIS package executes fine but it doesn't display the msg.

I was expecting to see the message before execution, am i wrong??

Comment: Your expectation is correct, you should see this fire before the dataflow executes.  In fact, once the modal window pops up, you're dataflow should not execute until you hit OK.  Could you provide some screenshots of the control flow and event handler?

Comment: you are running SSIS package from visual studio or from an application or something else?